# Vue JS - Data is undefined between dev and prod

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

this is my component. I get project raws from API, then i loop to create an array with months from project release date. On my template, i get months from my data. It works fine on dev but when i build my project my data months is undefined. I don't understand why ?

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="offset-2 col-8 my-5">
        <h1>Releases</h1>
      </div>
      <div v-if="this.months.length > 0" id="projects" class="offset-2 col-8">
        <div v-for="(month, index) in projects" :key="index" class="mb-5">
          <h3 class="mb-5">{{ this.months[index] }}</h3>
          <div v-for="project in month" :key="project.id" class="project mb-3">
            <p>{{ project.name }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  name: "List",
  data: () => {
    return {
      projects: [],
      months: [],
      range: {
        start: null,
        end: null,
      },
    };
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.range.start = new Date();
    const date_end = new Date();
    date_end.setFullYear(date_end.getFullYear() + 3);
    this.range.end = date_end;
    this.getProjectsByRange();
  },
  methods: {
    async getProjectsByRange() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("range", JSON.stringify(this.range));

      const datas = await this.axios
        .post("/projects/range", formData)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.data.projects;
        });

      datas.forEach((project) => {
        const month = moment(project.release_date).format("MMMM YYYY");
        if (!this.months.includes(month)) {
          this.months.push(month);
          this.projects[this.months.indexOf(month)] = [];
        }
        this.projects[this.months.indexOf(month)].push(project);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: There are any errors in the network tab for this request?

Comment: Nothin, my API request is fine. Juste javascript error in my console : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'months'). When i delete my <h3> it works fine ...

Comment: `console.log()` in different parts of your code, more so in the `thenable`, to inspect what response or data you are receiving from the request. Also, you could use an `if()` to check that the `datas` is not undefined before the `forEach()`

Comment: Try to remove the `this.` in `this.months[index]` in your template. You don't have to use `this` in Vue templates

Comment: @Kapcash gooood !! Remove this is correct, thanks a lot